What are the rules for demonstrative pronouns?
I'm wondering about how to determine what demonstrative pronoun points to. The specific example I have in mind is from 2024 DnD rules, but I'd like answers that focus on grammar if that's possible. The rule reads:

When you make the extra attack of the Light property, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action. You can make this extra attack only once per turn.

I hope it's enough to know that extra attack is a thing you can do, Light is a property that grants said extra attack, and Bonus Action and Attack action are resources you consume to e.g. do things like extra attack with.
The question is what the 2nd sentence's "this extra attack" refers to and thus what is limited. Is it Light property extra attacks in general or is it specifically such extra attacks made "as part of the Attack action"?
I'm hoping an answer would start with general rules for determining the use of such pronounce before applying them to this case. Is the rule ambiguous or clear? Which interpretation is more "natural"? etc.

"This extra attack" obviously refers to the specific "extra attack" mentioned in the previous sentence; I don't know what else it could conceivably refer to. I don't know if there are other possible Light property extra attacks you can make in other circumstances, or other extra attacks not related to Light that you can make in this circumstance, which might have a bearing. But there's no general rule, other than to work out what's most likely and eliminate what's impossible.

Have a look at some of these questions (not all are directly relevant but they should collectively help.)

'This' before a noun group is nowadays classified as a demonstrative determiner, not pronoun. // Here, you are right to be puzzled: the wording is ambiguous. As there isn't a new paragraph, perhaps the 'extra attacks made "as part of the Attack action" ' is more likely, but it can't be said to be the mandatory interpretation.

This type of analysis is rarely done purely based on the grammar. The referent is usually determined by the context, logic, and common sense.
